# How to get correct value from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on this simple search function that finds a person within a JSON Object. Here's my code:

```js
var personas = [
    {
        "name": "Luis",
        "lastname": "Gomez",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "name": "Maria",
        "lastname": "Lopez",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Lucero",
        "lastname": "Perez",
        "age": 30
    },
    {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "lastname": "Ruiz",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Teresa",
        "lastname": "Ponce",
        "age": 23
    }
];

function myFunction(userInput){

  if (userInput.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";

  }else{
    for(var i in personas){
     if(personas[i].name === userInput){
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Found";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Not Found";
    }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form >
Find person: <input type = "text" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
</form>

<div id = "info"></div>
```

**My issue:**
For some reason if I remove the **else** statement:

```
else{
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Not Found";
}
```

My program will be able to find the person's name. But let's say I type "Luis" and then delete the "s" the final string will say "Lui". However my program will still say "Found" even though "Lui" does not exist. Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `nombre` vs `name`.

Comment: @Siguza I just update but still not working

Comment: Also `break` once found, or you're gonna keep matching.

Comment: [There is no JSON in your code](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @progx — Did you read the article I just linked to? As for JSON Lint, it says: `Error: Parse error on line 1:
var personas = [{ "
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`. JavaScript literal syntax, while similar to JSON, is not JSON when it is in a JavaScript program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also build a array with elements which match and test if the result array is empty :

```js
var personas = [
    {
        "name": "Luis",
        "lastname": "Gomez",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "name": "Maria",
        "lastname": "Lopez",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Lucero",
        "lastname": "Perez",
        "age": 30
    },
    {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "lastname": "Ruiz",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Teresa",
        "lastname": "Ponce",
        "age": 23
    }
];
function myFunction(userInput){
  if (userInput.length == 0) 
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";
  else {
    if (personas.filter(x => x.name === userInput).length > 0)  
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Found";
    else 
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Not Found";
  }
}
```

```html
<form >
Find person: <input type = "text" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
</form>

<div id = "info"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) method:

```
function myFunction(userInput){

  if (userInput.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";
  }else{
     var persona = personas.find(function(persona) {
         return persona.name === userInput;
     })

    if (persona) {
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Found";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Not Found";
   }
 }
}
```

Issue: If you remove the else statement, the UI will not be updated when the name is not found.

Comment: [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can also be used in this case and currently has more browser support.

Answer (score 1):

Your is not working. The several problem may be:

1. you are using `nombre` instead of `name`
2. If once you match the `name` you should break the loop.
3. The problem you illustrated probably you had used `onkeydown` event instead of `onkeyup` event but now it looks fine.

running code is here:

```js
var personas = [
    {
        "name": "Luis",
        "lastname": "Gomez",
        "age": 25
    },
    {
        "name": "Maria",
        "lastname": "Lopez",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Lucero",
        "lastname": "Perez",
        "age": 30
    },
    {
        "name": "Daniel",
        "lastname": "Ruiz",
        "age": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Teresa",
        "lastname": "Ponce",
        "age": 23
    }
];

function myFunction(userInput){

  if (userInput.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";

  }else{
    for(var i in personas){
     if(personas[i].name === userInput){
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Found";
       break;
    }else{
      document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Not Found";
    }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form >
Find person: <input type = "text" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)"/>
</form>

<div id = "info"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens when you don't write `else` statement.

1. You type **L**, `myFunction` is called, where `userInput="L"` it doesn't satisfy `if` statement, hence nothing happens.
2. You type **u**, `myFunction` is called, where `userInput="Lu"` it doesn't satisfy `if` statement, hence nothing happens.
3. You type **i**, `myFunction` is called, where `userInput="Lui"` it doesn't satisfy `if` statement, hence nothing happens.
4. You type **s**, `myFunction` is called, where `userInput="Luis"` it satisfies `if` statement, hence `Found` is displayed in `info` div.
5. You delete **s**, `myFunction` is called, where `userInput="Lui"` it doesn't satisfy `if` statement, hence nothing happens.

But wait, what about `info` div? In the absence of `else` statement, there is no one to change `innerHTML` of `info` div. Hence it'll keep on displaying `Found` due to Step 4.

You can use debugger and set breakpoints to try it on your own.